# Combining 3 or more arrays in php

Tags: php, array

Assuming I have 5 arrays, all just indexed arrays, and I would like to combine them, this is the best way I can figure, has anyone found a more efficient solution?

```
function mymap_arrays() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $key  = array_shift($args);

    return array_combine($key, $args);
}

$keys   = array('u1', 'u2', 'u3');
$names  = array('Bob', 'Fred', 'Joe');
$emails = array('bob@mail.com', 'fred@mail.com', 'joe@mail.com');
$ids    = array(1, 2, 3);

$u_keys = array_fill( 0, count($names), array('name', 'email', 'id') );

$users  = array_combine($keys,
            array_map('mymap_arrays', $u_keys, $names, $emails, $ids)
          );
```

This returns:

```
Array
(
    [u1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bob
            [email] => bob@mail.com
            [id] => 1
        )

    [u2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Fred
            [email] => fred@mail.com
            [id] => 2
        )

    [u3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joe
            [email] => joe@mail.com
            [id] => 3
        )

)
```

EDIT: After a lot of benchmarking, this is the fastest solution I've come up with

```
function test_my_new() {
    $args    = func_get_args();
    $keys    = array_shift($args);
    $vkeys   = array_shift($args);
    $results = array();

    foreach($args as $key => $array) {
        $vkey = array_shift($vkeys);

        foreach($array as $akey => $val) {
            $result[ $keys[$akey] ][$vkey] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$keys   = array('u1', 'u2', 'u3');
$names  = array('Bob', 'Fred', 'Joe');
$emails = array('bob@mail.com', 'fred@mail.com', 'joe@mail.com');
$ids    = array(1,2,3);
$vkeys  = array('name', 'email', 'id');

test_my_new($keys, $vkeys, $names, $emails, $ids);
```

Comment: Do you have to use arrays? I think using classes to group related data (and behavior) would be a lot nicer.

Comment: Why would you even receive the data as such?

Comment: sorry for the delay, @c_maker & @phant0m this data is part of an api, I have no control over the format of the data, it actually comes in as delimited strings that I explode into arrays, I edited my question with my latest attempt

Comment: I have to agree with @c_maker.  I would really look at taking the input from the api and feeding it in to classes.  At the end of the day, do you really need this code to perform the faster, or to be more easily read and maintained?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following:

```
function combine_keys_with_arrays($keys, $arrays) {
    $results = array();

    foreach ($arrays as $subKey => $arr)
    {
       foreach ($keys as $index => $key)
       {
           $results[$key][$subKey] = $arr[$index];    
       }
    }

    return $results;
}

$keys    = array('u1', 'u2', 'u3');
$names   = array('Bob', 'Fred', 'Joe');
$emails  = array('bob@mail.com', 'fred@mail.com', 'joe@mail.com');
$ids     = array(1,2,3);

combine_keys_with_arrays($keys, array('name'  => $names,
                                      'email' => $emails,
                                      'id'    => $ids));
```

The second parameter to the function can be built as you need it.  It avoids array shifting and variable arguments, but I think it should be pretty fast.